# C#.net application not exiting after throwing web exception and unadvise()

Tags: c#, web-services, web-applications

I am developing a C# web client application which receives the content from a web server and displays it using a brower object after successful authentication. Ideally, when ever the application is exited and it needs to unsubscribe to network connection, we should call the method `Unadvise(cookie)` of `IConnectionPoint`. But when any web exception is thrown and the application needs to be closed, the application is not responding and it is not able to exit. When I comment the method `Unadvise(cookie)` it is working fine and the application is exiting succesfully.

Is there a way to solve the problem without commenting `Unadvise(cookie)`? .

Comment: If I don't call the Unadvise(cookie) atall, will there be any side effects? I read somewhere that a reference pointer for the interface is maintained in the system whenever we call Advise and Unadvise().What will happen to that reference pointer if we dont call Unadvise()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use multithreading - isolated thread for that call of unadvise, which you can kill on timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll definitely try this. Can you please tell me if I don't call the Unadvise(cookie) atall, will there be any side effects? I read somewhere that a reference pointer for the interface is maintained in the system whenever we call Advise() and Unadvise(). What will happen to that reference pointer if we dont call Unadvise()?

Comment: @Himanshu: If you don't call `Unadvise` you are basically still connected and may receive calls. If the code to handle the calls is unable to process the calls your application may crash. Trying to introduce multithreading without understanding the COM threading model instead of playing by the rules of the interfaces will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with apartments. I'm guessing here but if the object implementing `IConnectionPoint` is in a STA and wants to call back on another interface implemented by your code and your code does not process a message loop (i.e. if your thread is in an MTA which is the default for .NET 2.0 and forward) then the call back to your code hangs.

Depending on the threading model of your code and the objects you are using you could try to apply [`STAThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx) to your main method.